# Python error: "TypeError: Object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"

Tags: python, random

How can I fix this error? I am attempting to eliminate the number of names the user chooses.

```
names = []
def eliminate():
  votes = int(input("How many people would you like voted off? "))
  popped = random.shuffle(names)
  for i in range(votes):
    names.pop(len(popped))
  print("The remaining players are" + names)


for i in range(0,6):
    name = input("Give me a name: ")
    names.append(name)
eliminate()
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: `random.shuffle()` doesn't return anything; it modifies the list in place.  Perhaps you should copy the list (`popped = names.copy()`) and shuffle that.

Answer (score 2):

[`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) returns `None`, not the shuffled list which is actually shuffled in place. Since you want to pop the last item in the list you do not need to provide an index to `pop()`:

```
random.shuffle(names)
for i in range(votes):
    names.pop()
```

Comment: you could also use list slicing to truncate the names list using votes: `names = names[votes:]`

Comment: @AnthonyPerot: it's slightly different in that the items would be removed from the front of the list vs. the end of the list. In this case there is no difference because the list is randomly sorted. You could do `names = names[:-votes]`

Comment: oh yeah, sure, he's popping, nice catch!

Answer (score 1):

`random.shuffle(names)` doesn't return anything or return `None`. However, your list "names" is being shuffled.
You can get the result:

```
random.shuffle(names)
for i in range(votes):
    del names[-1]
```